Why is my key up function not working for input field with ID #lastshop
I have several input fields that I use to Calculate the Cost of the last shop visit. My keyup function works fine but for me to get correct Last Shop Visit Cost I often have to type twice. On all the other input fields my keyup function works as I type.
To understand my problem simply put 1000 in the field called Invoice value, the field called cost of last shop visit should be equal to 1000 as you type but instead i have to press enter twice to get the fields to be equal. It seems the output is lagging.
I tried the code below, for some reason it seems the input field with #lastshop is lagging in getting a result.


$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get value on keyup funtion
  $("#lastshop, #invoice, #aoidisks, #aoibnv, #aoilabour, #aoival, #stolbnv, #stoldisks, #stolval,#aoilabour ")
    .keyup(
      function() {
        var aoival = 0;
        var aoilabour = 0;
        var lastshop = 0;
        var stolbnv = 0;
        var g = Number($("#lastshop").val());
        var a = Number($("#invoice").val());
        var b = Number($("#aoidisks").val());
        var c = Number($("#aoibnv").val());
        var d = Number($("#aoilabour").val());
        var e = Number($("#stolbnv").val());
        var f = Number($("#stoldisks").val());
        g = c + d + e;
        aoilabour = a - b - c;
        var aoival = aoilabour + b + c;
        $('#aoilabour').val(aoilabour);
        $('#aoival').val(aoival);
        var stolval = e + f;
        $('#stolval').val(stolval);
        $('#lastshop').val(g);



      });
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<center>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="">Date</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="thedate" id="thedate" class='thedate'>
    </p>
    <p><label for="">Engine</label></p>
    <p>
      <select name="" id="">
        <option value="" selected>Select Engine</option>
        <option value="">E268509</option>
        <option value="">E268588</option>
        <option value="">E268660</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p><label for="">Cycles To Run</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="cyclestorun" id="cyclestorun"></p>
    <label for="">Invoice Value</label>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name='invoice' id='invoice' class='invoice'>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">AOI Disks</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="aoidisks" id="aoidisks">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">AOI B & V</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="aoibnv" id="aoibnv">
    </P>
    <p>
      <label for="">AOI Labour</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="aoilabour" id="aoilabour" readonly>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">AOI Value</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="aoival" id="aoival" readonly>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">Stol B & V</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="stolbnv" id="stolbnv">
    </P>
    <p>
      <label for="">Stol Disks</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="stoldisks" id="stoldisks">
    </P>
    <p>
      <label for="">Stol Value</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="stolval" id="stolval" readonly>
    </P>
    <p>
      <label for="">Cost of Last Shop Visit</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="lastshop" id="lastshop" readonly>
    </P>
  </form>
</center>




Your updated explanation / repro steps make it clear what the problem is.  The issue is that you are reading the current values of the calculation, then updating them, then assuming the final calculation will be based on the updated values - it's not, your code uses the values as they were at the time you read them. Updated code showing a possible fix that demonstrates the issue (by fixing it): jsfiddle.net/fxv79gyz or jsfiddle.net/fxv79gyz/1

Change g = c + aoilabou + e; $('#lastshop').val(g);

You might also like to use .on("input", rather than .keyup as it will pick up other changes such as mouse-paste

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  For example, after entering 1000 into the input... The output value you reference is calculated with g = c + d + e;  When I debug I find that c is 0 and d is 100 and e is 0.  From that calculation, I expect the result to be 100, not 1000.

@fdomn-m so you helped me fix this code a couple of days ago. I am doing research so that I do not have this problem again. Could you explain how you solved this problem, like is there a term to describe what you did ?

The easiest explanation is: dry-run (not to be confused with DRY).  That means "running" your code "offline" where you act as the computer.  You can use pen+paper to keep track of what's happening.  Step through each line making a note of each variable state and, as it changes, what it changes to.  So initial variables=0, then some variables taken from inputs, calculate g, update some values - ah, some of those values are used in the g calculation, but they've now changed - update the total with g.

The updated "put 1000 in the field called Invoice value" was also a big clue.  This means there's no actual problem with the key up on the total/last field (which is what you were describing prior to this).  Trying the code out by putting different values in (not just pressing enter) showed the calculation one-step behind.

Here is a delegated version using 'input' and making sure the values are numeric


jQuery($ => {
  // Get value on keyup funtion
  $("form")
    .on('input', () => {
      var aoival, aoilabour, lastshop, stolval;
      var invoice = Number($("#invoice").val());
      var aoidisks = Number($("#aoidisks").val());
      var aoibnv = Number($("#aoibnv").val());
      var aoilabourInput = Number($("#aoilabour").val());
      var stolbnv = Number($("#stolbnv").val());
      var stoldisks = Number($("#stoldisks").val());

      // Calculate the last shop total
      lastshop = aoibnv + aoilabourInput + stolbnv;
      $('#lastshop').val(lastshop);

      // Calculate AOI labour and value
      aoilabour = invoice - aoidisks - aoibnv;
      $('#aoilabour').val(aoilabour);
      aoival = aoilabour + aoidisks + aoibnv;
      $('#aoival').val(aoival);

      // Calculate Stolen value
      stolval = stolbnv + stoldisks;
      $('#stolval').val(stolval);
    });
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<center>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="">Date</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="thedate" id="thedate" class='thedate'>
    </p>
    <p><label for="">Engine</label></p>
    <p>
      <select name="" id="">
        <option value="" selected>Select Engine</option>
        <option value="">E268509</option>
        <option value="">E268588</option>
        <option value="">E268660</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p><label for="">Cycles To Run</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="cyclestorun" id="cyclestorun"></p>
    <label for="">Invoice Value</label>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name='invoice' id='invoice' class='invoice'>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">AOI Disks</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="aoidisks" id="aoidisks">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">AOI B & V</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="aoibnv" id="aoibnv">
    </P>
    <p>
      <label for="">AOI Labour</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="aoilabour" id="aoilabour" readonly>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">AOI Value</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="aoival" id="aoival" readonly>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="">Stol B & V</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="stolbnv" id="stolbnv">
    </P>
    <p>
      <label for="">Stol Disks</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="stoldisks" id="stoldisks">
    </P>
    <p>
      <label for="">Stol Value</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="stolval" id="stolval" readonly>
    </P>
    <p>
      <label for="">Cost of Last Shop Visit</label>
    </p>
    <P>
      <input type="text" name="lastshop" id="lastshop" readonly>
    </P>
  </form>
</center>



